# Trouble using DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json, datacontractserializer

This is the first time I've used the `DataContractSerializer` so forgive me if this question is basic, but I can't seem to find a solution.

I've set up the class `AuthTokenContract`

```
[DataContract]
public class AuthTokenContract
{
    [DataMember(Name="token")]
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

And my method to bind the `JSON` response to my model

```
public Guid GetAuthToken()
{
    var queryString = new Uri(String.Format("token?apiKey={0}", _apiKey), UriKind.Relative);
    var requestUrl = new Uri(_baseUrl, queryString);

    var contract = GetResponse<AuthTokenContract>(requestUrl);

    return Guid.NewGuid(); // Ignore
}

private TContractType GetResponse<TContractType>(Uri requestUrl) where TContractType : class 
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TContractType));
        object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
        return objResponse as TContractType;
    }
}
```

This is the response I am getting from the URL:

```
{
    "result":
        {
            "token":"8D53ED8E-DE75-423B-AC76-DADEF7139D98"
        },
    "warnings":[]
}
```

However, `contract.Token` is always `null`. I know it is returning the `JSON` above, but I can't get it to translate correctly. Any help?

Comment: make your class public

Comment: it's internal, my first comment I was looking at the wrong class.

Comment: @TMcKeown DataContractSerializer works with internal classes.

Comment: wondering why you use an internal class for something that is going to transport?

Comment: I know it will, just don't understand why you would define it that way.

Comment: your example makes no sense...  what class are you serializing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your contract to

```
[DataContract]
public class AuthTokenContract
{
    [DataMember(Name = "result")]
    public Result result { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "warnings")]
    public string[] Warnings { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    [DataMember(Name = "token")]
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: With this, `Result` and `Warnings` were both `null`

Comment: why don't you post your code that issues the serialization?  Your example doesn't match what you are expecting...  you post 1 class with 1 property... the example shows different properties... makes no sense.

Comment: Apologies Nasreddine, I didn't add `[DataContract]` to `AuthTokenContract`. Thanks so much!